# Verifying properties of a group action

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G=\mathbb{R}^*$ and $X=\mathbb{R}^2$.  The action is $s \in G$ such that $^s(x_1,x_2)=(sx_1,s^{-1}x_2)$.

(i)  Verifying this is indeed a group action.

Let $g_1,g_2\in G$.  Then $^{g_1}(^{g_2}(x_1,x_2))= {^{g_1}}(g_2x,g_2^{-1}x)=(g_1g_2x_1,g_1^{-1}g_2^{-1}x_2)$.  I'm stuck verifying that ${^{g_1}}({^{g_2}}(x_1,x_2))={^{g_1g_2}}(x_1,x_2)$.  Because $\mathbb{R}^*$ is commutative, can I rearrage the elements acting on $(x_1,x_2)$ in a way to get the desired result?  That is, can I just rearrange it as such: $(g_1g_2x_1,g_1^{-1}g_2^{-1}x_2)=(g_1g_2x_1,g_2^{-1}g_1^{-1}x_2)=(g_1g_2x_1,(g_1g_2)^{-1}x_2)={^{g_1g_2}}(x_1,x_2)$

(ii)  Given the function $f(x_1,x_2)=x_1x_2$, show that $f$ is an invariant function.

First if we fix $(x_1,x_2)$ and we let $G$ act on the coordinates, it scales the coordinates and changes the signs (reflects).  It creates lines that never hit the origin (unless $x_1,x_2$ both equal 0)$.  However, I'm not sure how to show this is invariant by understanding the orbits.

Comment: Ad (i), yes, you can. And you need to. If $G$ weren't commutative, it would not be a group action. Ad (ii) Just show that $f\bigl(^s(x_1,x_2)\bigr) =f\bigl((x_1,x_2)\bigr)$ for all $s \in G$.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow for (ii).

Comment: That's what invariant means, that $f$ is constant on the orbits. Just plug in the definition of the group action. (Again, the commutativity of multiplication in $\mathbb{R}$ is not entirely unimportant.)

Comment: So let $f({^s}(x_1,x_2))=sx_1s^{-1}x_2=\text{...commutivity and associativity...}=x_1x_2$...yay we win?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: This is going to sound like a weird question, but $f^{-1}(r)$ (r \in \mathbb{R}) is the union of orbits correct?  If so, are there only "a few" $f^{-1}(r)$.

Comment: Well, apart from $f^{-1}(0)$, all level sets of $f$ are orbits. $f^{-1}(0)$ is the union of three orbits.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that?  I think I'm visualizing this all wrong.  Also, I don't see how that computation shows that this function is an invariant.

Comment: If you have a group action $(g,x) \mapsto g \cdot x$, a function $f\colon X \to Y$ is an invariant function, if $f(g\cdot x) = f(x)$ for all $g,x$. When $x_1 \neq 0 \neq x_2$, the orbit of $(x_1,x_2)$ under the given action is just the hyperbola $xy = x_1x_2$. The orbits of $(0,1),\, (1,0),\,(0,0)$ are a little different.

Comment: Maybe our definitions are equivalent.  If we have a group action then a function $f:X \to Y$ is said to be invariant if for any two points on the same orbit then $f(x)=f(y)$.

Comment: Well, $x$ and $y$ are in the same orbit if and only if there is a $g$ with $y = g\cdot x$.